# Send Logstash logs to Kibana remote server

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am new to ELK Stack and trying to view logs on kibana which is hosted on different server. Following are my configurations for **Filebeat** and **logstash** in my **localhost pc** and **logstash is succesfully recieving logs from filbeat.**

I am facing a lot of confusion in creating an index pattern in kibana. how do i know the index variable parameters **[@metadata][beat]** and **[@metadata][version]** present in output node in logstash.conf so that i will create an index pattern and access the same in kibana discover page

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/mahesh/Documents/refactor/nomi/unity/media/*.log

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\|%{GREEDYDATA:module}\|%{GREEDYDATA:content}" }
  }
  date {
    locale => "en"
    match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    timezone => "America/New_York"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elk_server_ip:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" 
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list your indexes by using:
`elk_server_ip:9200/_cat/indices`
More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html)

Comment: thanks a lot ....there were many but i found one index with todays date and created and index pattern there after which i went to kibana discover.. it says "No results match your search criteria" for my index pattern

Comment: You can use wildcard to create your pattern.

Comment: u mean i can also give index in output node like index -> "sample_index" ?

Comment: I guess this can help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/logstash-output.html

Comment: one last doubt....how do i know my config is metricbeat (or) filebeat? is there any command to know that?

Comment: Not sure, but as per their docs, if you don't change it, the default value will be used